# Setting <img> with saved absolute path | MYSQL - Multer and EJS

Tags: javascript, path, ejs, multer, absolute

Im saving my images with multer and im also saving the absolute path with SQL.
**¿How can i display the img in EJS with the path saved in mysql? ¿is there any way to transform it to a relative path?**

Here is my HTML code:

```
    <ul>
      <% for (let i = 0; i < rigs.length; i++) { %>
        <li>
          <a href="/rig/<%=rigs[i].id_rigs%>"> </a>
          <img src="<%=rigs[i].image %>">
          <%=rigs[i].titulo %>
          <%=rigs[i].precio %>
          <%=rigs[i].especificaciones %>
        </li>
     <% } %>
    </ul>
  </main>
```

The path of the img is C:\Users\Alan\Desktop\Nueva carpeta-grupo_1_CipherRigs\public\img\rigs\group-1660204927004.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

Yo,  That bad practice

I mean An Attacker could use that information somehow

either way, I advise you to start saving your image path from
`C:\Users\Alan\Desktop\Nueva carpeta-grupo_1_CipherRigs\public\img\rigs\group-1660204927004.jpg` to `img\rigs\group-1660204927004.jpg`

Am sure in Your server you have a snippet

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

or you are saving it in a public dir

So while passing or writing your file path to the DB make its look like this
`img\rigs\group-1660204927004.jpg` or `\img\rigs\group-1660204927004.jpg`

And to fix your current problem

```
    <ul>
  <% for (let i = 0; i < rigs.length; i++) { %>
    <li>
      <a href="/rig/<%=rigs[i].id_rigs%>"> </a>
      <!-- Add This-->
      <img src="/img/rigs/<%=rigs[i].image.split("public\img\rigs")[1] %>">
      <%=rigs[i].titulo %>
      <%=rigs[i].precio %>
      <%=rigs[i].especificaciones %>
    </li>
 <% } %>
</ul>
```